# Angular - How to debounce PipeTransform?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe, debouncing

I am using `*ngFor` to display a collection, I also have one `input` which will be used as a filter criteria (this `input` is a `formControl`). Now I have added a `PipeTransform` to filter my collection based on that `input`.
Everything works as expected but I can't figure out how to debounce. I want my `filterPipe` to be called 0.5s after last keystroke inside `input` but at the moment it is called instantly after any change inside my `input`.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="test-ctr">
      <div class="form-ctr">
        <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="filterForm">>
          <input formControlName="nick" placeholder="ex. hdw"> 
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="app-cards-ctr">
        <div class="app-card-ctr" *ngFor="let nick of nicks | filterPipe: filterForm.get('nick')?.value">
          <app-card [nick]="nick"></app-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Component.ts:**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
    })
    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
      nicks: string[] = ['Siema', 'Elo', 'Tu', 'Hdw3DCtV', 'and', 'Gównow', 'Zdzisiu11', 'Zdzisiu1','Zdzisiu2','Zdzisiu3','Zdzisiu4','Zdzisiu5'];
    
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
    
      filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        nick: ['']
      })
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

**Pipe.ts:**

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Pipe({ name: 'filterPipe', pure: true })
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: string[], arg: string): string[] {
        console.log(arg);
        return value.filter(
          (e) => e.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Never tried this, but maybe this? filterPipe:  (filterForm.get('nick')?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)) |  async)

Comment: @MikeOne I have tried it but it still triggers filterPipe on any change instantly. I didn't investigate it too much so maybe I did something wrong but I think that debounce in this case would happen inside filterPipe if I subscribed there, not before calling filterPipe. I think I somehow need to delay my from so it doesn't detect changes instantly but I don't know if that's possible or if it would be a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working example in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wyh5jv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

#### HTML:

```
<h3>Filter:</h3>
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="nick" />
</form>

<h3>Nicks:</h3>
<div *ngFor="let nick of nicks | filterPipe: (debouncedControl$ | async)">
  {{ nick }}
</div>
```

#### Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  nicks: string[] = [
    'Siema',
    'Elo',
    'Tu',
    'Hdw3DCtV',
    'and',
    'Gównow',
    'Zdzisiu11',
    'Zdzisiu1',
    'Zdzisiu2',
    'Zdzisiu3',
    'Zdzisiu4',
    'Zdzisiu5',
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    nick: [''],
  });

  debouncedControl$ = this.filterForm.controls.nick.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(500)
  );
}
```

#### Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: string[], inputValue: string): string[] {
    return values.filter((v) => {
      return (
        v.toLowerCase().indexOf((inputValue || '').toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
      );
    });
  }
}
```

All that said, this is probably not a scenario where I would reach for an angular pipe.

#### Alternate component solution:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'alternate',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="filterForm">
        <input type="text" formControlName="nick" />
    </form>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let nick of filteredNicks$ | async"> {{nick}} </li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class AlternateSolutionComponent {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  nicks = ['Siema', 'Elo', 'Tu'];

  lowercaseIncludes(a: string, b: string): boolean {
    return a.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(b.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1;
  }

  filterForm = this.formBuilder.group({ nick: [''] });

  filteredNicks$ = this.filterForm.controls.nick.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(500),
    map((inputValue) => {
      return this.nicks.filter((nick) =>
        this.lowercaseIncludes(nick, inputValue)
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: I like your alternate solution but I think your first suggestion is a little different than what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to delay execution of `transform` function inside `filterPipe`, not to delay filtering itself which happens already inside that `transform` function. In other words, how can I debounce my input in a way that `transform` function will be called only once and only after someone finishes typing (e.g 0.5s after the last keystroke)

Comment: @hdw3 - okay, I think I understand. Updated the answer and stackblitz. Instead of handling the observable inside the filter pipe, you can debounce the input in your component and pass that through the `async` pipe to your `filterPipe`. Does the first suggestion better match your original questions?

Answer (score 2):

For me, best approach is to use the pipe inside the component and not in the template.

```
constructor(
  private filterPipe: FilterPipe
) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.filterForm.controls.nick.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(500),
    map(value => {
      this.nicks.forEach(nick => {
          nick = this.filterPipe.transform(value, nick); // or what you want to do
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a decorator that debounce call of function

```
export function ngDebounce(milleseconds: number) {
let timeoutRef:any;
return function(target:Object, _: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
      timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => {
        original.apply(this, args);
      }, milleseconds);
    }
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

and then just change the search variable on input

```
<input type="text" (input)="changeInput($event.target.value)" >
<div *ngFor="let nick of nicks | filterPipe: searchInput">
  {{ nick }}
</div>
```

component.ts

```
searchInput: string = ''


  @ngDebounce(400)
  changeInput(value: string) {
    this.searchInput = value
    this.ref.markForCheck();
  }
```